# Generate pcolor based on 3 vectors

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to pcolor the vector `V` given 2 coordinates `X` and `Y` stored in df called `data`.
Here is the kind of data I have

```
X   Y   V
-54.008023  -3.089502   0.08
16.380733   -2.927304   0.18
114.405305  -108.283068 0.07
-64.997610  -3.412201   0.20
-16.572613  -9.157832   0.07
46.412991   -0.873716   0.07
-98.040016  6.404147    0.10
-42.512056  -5.814152   0.07
-99.183301  6.571170    0.07
83.545445   5.975908    0.07
9.264582    1.684954    0.07
71.632759   8.592899    0.21
88.676600   11.641016   0.15
-50.230426  -6.045050   0.16
-94.874756  18.088942   0.10
-30.455823  -8.512615   0.07
89.546425   2.761240    0.26
-20.746505  -5.834019   0.07
10.763826   -4.328090   0.07
-37.145986  -9.023120   0.50
45.122722   1.663442    0.07
-29.196808  -11.210683  0.07
38.553098   0.604973    0.28
-23.069677  -6.899701   0.20
10.913633   -14.562856  0.10
```

I have the start of the code which is creating the `X`, `Y` meshgrid:

```
y, x = np.mgrid[slice(data.X.min(), data.X.max(), 5),
                slice(data.Y.min(), data.Y.max(), 5)]
```

But I cannot manage to generate the corresponding `v(x,y)` vector that would allow me to plot it:

```
plt.pcolor(x, y, v, cmap='YlOrRd')
```

Comment: `pcolor` and `pcolormesh` plot 2D arrays. `V` is a 1D series. What do you want `v(x, y)` to be? Do you just want a scatter plot of Y vs X, colored by the value of V?

Answer (score 0):

use `scipy.interpolate.griddata`:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pylab as pl
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np
import io

text = """-54.008023  -3.089502   0.08
16.380733   -2.927304   0.18
114.405305  -108.283068 0.07
-64.997610  -3.412201   0.20
-16.572613  -9.157832   0.07
46.412991   -0.873716   0.07
-98.040016  6.404147    0.10
-42.512056  -5.814152   0.07
-99.183301  6.571170    0.07
83.545445   5.975908    0.07
9.264582    1.684954    0.07
71.632759   8.592899    0.21
88.676600   11.641016   0.15
-50.230426  -6.045050   0.16
-94.874756  18.088942   0.10
-30.455823  -8.512615   0.07
89.546425   2.761240    0.26
-20.746505  -5.834019   0.07
10.763826   -4.328090   0.07
-37.145986  -9.023120   0.50
45.122722   1.663442    0.07
-29.196808  -11.210683  0.07
38.553098   0.604973    0.28
-23.069677  -6.899701   0.20
10.913633   -14.562856  0.10
"""

f = io.StringIO(text)
a = np.loadtxt(f)
x, y, v = a.T

X, Y = np.mgrid[x.min():x.max():10j, y.min():y.max():10j]
points = np.c_[X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]

V = interpolate.griddata(np.c_[x, y], v, points).reshape(X.shape)

pl.pcolor(X, Y, V)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks HYRY, it seems great. So how does it handle multiple values in a same square? It does the mean of all value inside the square?